# I keep getting a json parse error when using GraphQL and Apollo client

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

I'm using a SWAPI Wrapper for this project. And my code looks like it's right, but for some reason I keep getting a `JSON Parse error: Unexpected EOF` when trying to load the data. And when I do the following query at the GraphQL endpoint, it works:

```
{
  allPeople {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        name
        birthYear
        gender
        homeworld {
          name
        }
        species {
          name
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

...but when I do it in my file, I just get that error mentioned above. Below is my code:

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

import{
  ApolloClient,
  ApolloProvider,
  HttpLink,
  InMemoryCache,
} from '@apollo/client'

const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  link: new HttpLink({
    uri: "https://graphql.org/swapi-graphql",
    useGETForQueries: true,
    fetchOptions: {
      mode: 'no-cors',
    }
  })
})

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <App />
    </ApolloProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

reportWebVitals();
```

App.js

```
import './App.css';

import { useQuery, gql } from '@apollo/client';

const ALL_PERSONS = gql`
query {
  allPeople {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        name
        birthYear
        gender
        homeworld {
          name
        }
        species {
          name
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
`;

function App() {
  const { loading, error, data} = useQuery(ALL_PERSONS);

  if (loading){
    return (
      <div>
        Loading...
      </div>
    );
  }
  else if (error){
    return(
      <div>
        <h1>Something went wrong!</h1>
        <p>Name: {error.name}</p>
        <p>Message: {error.message}</p>
        <p>Data: {data}</p>

      </div>
    );
  }
  else{
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Star Wars API</h1>
        <div>
          {data}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Any help is appreciated! I'm new to using Apollo Client and GraphQL

Comment: why GET? check/show network response

Comment: if I remove "useGETForQueries", I get this response: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 ()". And then if I also remove "mode: no-cors", I get these: "Failed to load resource: Preflight response is not successful", "Fetch API cannot load https://graphql.org/swapi-graphql due to access control checks."